# Logic with classes in jenkins pipeline doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a jenkins pipeline that **takes the latest version of a project and use it's artifacts** (like docker images) for end-to-end tests.

The pipeline might look complicated but it's rather simple. The **`ProjectVersion` class is there for sorting the versions**. The most complex part is in compareTo method which is meant to be used when selecting the greatest versions (there was going to be more complex logic with regex matching later on)

There is commented out part with sorting because it fails with it when is used.

The pipeline:

```
class ProjectVersion implements Comparable<ProjectVersion>, Serializable {

    private String version;

    public final String get() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public ProjectVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public int compareTo(ProjectVersion that) {
        if(that == null)
            return 1;
        String[] thisParts = this.get().split("\\.");
        String[] thatParts = that.get().split("\\.");
        int length = Math.max(thisParts.length, thatParts.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int thisPart = i < thisParts.length ?
                    tryToParse(thisParts[i]) : 0;
            int thatPart = i < thatParts.length ?
                    tryToParse(thatParts[i]) : 0;
            if(thisPart < thatPart)
                return -1;
            if(thisPart > thatPart)
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int tryToParse(String part) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(part)
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    boolean equals(Object that) {
        if(this == that)
            return true;
        if(that == null)
            return false;
        if(this.getClass() != that.getClass())
            return false;
        return this.compareTo((ProjectVersion) that) == 0;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProjectVersion{" +
                "version='" + version + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


def getJSON(url) {
    sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl -s ${url} 2>&1 | tee result.json")
    readFile('result.json').trim()
}

def getVersions(String url) {
    def json =   readJSON text: getJSON(url)
    def allVersions = json.children.findAll { child -> child.folder }
            .collect { it.uri.substring(1).trim() }
    return sort(allVersions)
}

@NonCPS
def sort(allVersions) {
    return allVersions
            .collect { it-> new ProjectVersion(it) }
//            .sort{it1, it2 -> it1.compareTo(it2)}
//            .reverse()

}

def getVersions() {
    def versions = getVersions(MVN_ARTIFACTORY)
    println(versions.toString())
    def lastVersion = versions.iterator().next()
    println(lastVersion.toString())
    versions
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label JENKINS_NODES
    }
    stages {
        stage('Get the right version') {
            steps {
                getVersions()
            }
        }
    }
```

The result:

```
// not important stuff here

+ curl -s ************************ // not important
+ tee result.json
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
ProjectVersion{version='1.5.10'}
[Pipeline] echo
ProjectVersion{version='1.5.10'}
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

The **first echo should print all versions in collection** - yet **the variable is obviously instance of the `ProjectVersion`** class **not a list**. How is it even possible?

I was trying to play around with `@NonCPS` annotation but with no luck.

I'm quite sure that the groovy code part is working. When I try to run it from groovy console (and replace json parsing to `new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new URL(url).getText())`) it works. The expected result (without sorting) is:

```
[ProjectVersion{version='1.5.10'}, ProjectVersion{version='1.5.11'}, ProjectVersion{version='1.6.0.31'}, ProjectVersion{version='1.6.0.32'}, ProjectVersion{version='1.6.0.33'}, ProjectVersion{version='1.6.0.34'}, ProjectVersion{version='1.6.0.35'}, ProjectVersion{version='1.6.0.36'}, ProjectVersion{version='2.0.0'}, ProjectVersion{version='2.0.10'}]
```

Thank you for you help.

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a @NonCPS annotation missing for your *toString* method:

```
@Override @NonCPS
public String toString() {
    return "ProjectVersion{" +
            "version='" + version + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```